# Spiral pattern and Fibonacci numbers

Tags: graphics

I'm want to generate a 2D spiral pattern like the the one shown in the following figure. I can generate the spirals one by one, but I think there ought to be a more efficient method for generating such a scattered point pattern. Could anybody give me a hint?

[image: sunflower pattern]

Comment: I think you need to show your existing approach to be in with a chance of getting an answer to this. As it is, it's rather unclear what you expect other than for people to solve the problem for you.

Comment: Mandatory reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOIP_Z_-0Hs :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard her videos are awesome!

Comment: here is the original picture if someone wants to give it a try: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Mother_and_daughter.jpg

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is called a [**spiral phyllotaxis pattern**](https://www.google.com/search?q=phyllotaxis%20pattern). There is a lot of *Mathematica* material for this. [**Chris Carlson's blog entry**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/28/how-i-made-wine-glasses-from-sunflowers/) gives you some code right from the start:

```
g = 2 Pi (1 - 1/GoldenRatio);
PolarCoordinate[r_, t_] := r {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
Graphics[Point[Table[PolarCoordinate[Sqrt[i], i g], {i, 1, 1000}]]]
```

[image: phyllotaxis pattern]

The Demonstrations project [**has a lot too**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=phyllotaxis); for example:

- [**Phyllotaxis Spirals, Stephen Wolfram**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PhyllotaxisSpirals/)
- [**Phyllotaxis Explained, Claude Fabre**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PhyllotaxisExplained/)

[image: Phyllotaxis Spirals, Stephen Wolfram]

[image: Phyllotaxis Explained, Claude Fabre]

Comment: I have a question though: how to determine the number of spirals in such a pattern for a given phi (here *g*)? [Claude Fabre](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PhyllotaxisExplained/) showed that all points locate on a single spiral curve, but the pattern here seems several spirals exist as well as depicted in the sunflower pattern (cyan curves).

Comment: @TonyDong I think you just need to count how many dots you place for full single angle turn 2Pi.