# Fitting Vogel's formula for phyllotaxis to the image of a flower

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-optimization

After having read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20924/spiral-pattern-and-fibonacci-numbers) question I was inspired to investigate how we could take an image of a plant displaying phyllotaxis and fit Vogel's model of phyllotaxis to the image. The theory is [very simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunflower#Mathematical_model_of_floret_arrangement).

The model is this:

$r = c\sqrt{n}$

$\theta = 137.508 n$

And courtesy of [shrx](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6849/shrx) we have the original image of the sunflower in that other question, located [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Mother_and_daughter.jpg). To begin with I wanted to retrieve the positions of the florets in the image, which I did using `LocatorPane`:

[image: locatorpane]

These are the points:

```
florets = {{182.4,288.},{150.,286.},{166.6,274.5},{181.4,261.},{200.6,274.},{214.6,256.},{234.2,256.},{220.6,279.5},{196.2,247.5},{220.,237.},{238.,235.},{259.2,224.5},{257.8,252.},{261.8,202.5},{284.,193.},{256.8,183.},{274.2,169.5},{257.6,148.5},{247.2,166.5},{233.4,179.},{239.2,196.},{239.4,215.},{224.4,218.5},{223.8,198.},{212.,179.},{222.,163.5},{236.4,152.},{249.4,131.},{250.2,110.5},{268.6,127.},{227.4,82.5},{233.2,102.},{231.,125.},{221.6,142.5},{213.2,123.5},{213.2,102.},{207.4,82.},{196.2,64.},{183.2,84.},{169.4,72.},{194.6,105.},{194.4,122.},{204.,139.5},{203.6,161.},{194.8,178.},{201.4,195.5},{207.2,208.5},{204.2,228.5},{186.2,232.5},{172.,244.},{155.8,258.},{136.,264.},{116.8,259.5},{96.4,252.5},{74.8,246.5},{84.,226.},{102.4,235.},{105.6,215.5},{122.4,221.5},{118.6,239.5},{138.,242.5},{155.4,235.5},{167.6,223.5},{187.8,212.5},{186.4,194.5},{171.6,208.5},{153.2,212.5},{139.8,223.5},{134.,207.},{119.,201.},{120.8,182.},{137.2,185.5},{149.6,193.5},{165.2,193.5},{177.6,178.5},{161.,180.},{165.2,164.5},{184.4,163.5},{188.6,146.5},{178.,136.5},{177.6,114.5},{169.8,97.},{150.2,85.5},{130.4,74.5},{134.2,96.5},{151.8,105.5},{162.,125.},{156.4,140.},{172.4,150.},{149.4,155.5},{145.8,173.5},{130.8,166.5},{124.8,151.},{140.6,140.5},{143.,123.},{121.8,130.},{125.8,111.5},{106.4,110.5},{113.8,89.5},{102.8,129.},{102.4,149.},{110.6,168.},{102.,190.},{91.2,172.5},{80.8,158.},{84.6,136.},{84.8,112.5},{57.4,148.},{64.4,171.5},{48.2,193.5},{65.,210.},{76.2,188.5},{89.8,203.},{123.8,284.}};
```

Later I will use the fact that $n = (\frac{r}{c})^2$ such that to order the list according to index n, we can use `SortBy[florets,Norm]`.

In order to fit Vogel's model to this data I will try to use the following degrees of freedom:

- The constant `c`
- The origin `{x0, y0}`
- Angular offset

And I will use `NMinimize`. My *Mathematica* code for this is as follows:

```
phi[n_, ang_] := ang n
r[n_, c_] := c Sqrt[n]
pos[phi_, r_, {x0_, y0_}, phi0_] := {x0, y0} + {r Cos[(phi + phi0) Degree], r Sin[(phi + phi0) Degree]}

NMinimize[{
  Total[
   Norm[#[[2]] - #[[1]]] & /@ Partition[
     Riffle[
      SortBy[Array[pos[phi[#, ang], r[#, c], {x0, y0}, phi0] &, Length@florets], Norm],
      SortBy[florets, Norm]
      ], 2]
   ],
  c > 0, 137 < ang < 138
  }, {ang, c, x0, y0, phi0}]
```

`Riffle` and the `SortBy` trick puts the corresponding points with the same index `n` next to each other. `Partition` finds these pairs and then I measure the difference between them. When the points are almost on top of each other the difference should be very small, instead I get something quite large:

```
{8318.44, {ang -> 137.055, c -> 1.21577, x0 -> 169.497, y0 -> 176.741,
   phi0 -> 41.2544}}
```

Now `Mean[florets]` gives `{168.811, 178.544}` so the `{x0, y0}` is probably correct. **But why is the fit as bad as it is?**

I've worked through this problem using only *Mathematica*. If the problem could be for example precision in the way that I find the positions, please suggest a different way to do it using *Mathematica*. What you see is the best I could do...

Comment: I haven't looked at your code in detail, but using `Riffle` and `SortBy` inside `NMinimize` sounds like a bad idea. It makes your function hard to differentiate, and possible even discontinuous, too.

Comment: In any case, shouldn't you be sorting by `Norm[# - {x0,y0}]&` instead of just `Norm`?

Comment: @RahulNarain As for discontinuity etc. that's OK as long as it doesn't give me the wrong result. Because `NMinimize` is very fast, it doesn't appear to have a problem with it. As for sorting, I tried that now and it doesn't change the result.

Comment: What is `pos`??

Comment: @s0rce Sorry... It's included now.

Comment: Well this doesn't fit it but ang is in radians not degrees.

Comment: @s0rce Thanks, I changed `pos` to account for the values being in degrees.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I tried working in polar coordinates and fitting `r` and `theta` independently, I fixed `x0` and `y0` as the mean value. Not a great fit, but not terrible. I'm not sure how much including a free `x0` and `y0` would improve the fit or if the data simply doesn't match the model perfectly. We can improve the `r(n)` by adjusting the exponent during the fit instead of fixing it at `1/2 (sqrt)`, it ends up being close to `0.6`.

```
florets = Rescale[Rescale@florets, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}];
florets = # - Mean@florets & /@ florets;

polar = Transpose@
   Reverse@Transpose@
     CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Polar", florets];
polar = SortBy[polar, Last];
const = First@
  LinearModelFit[polar[[All, 2]], Sqrt[n], n, 
    IncludeConstantBasis -> False]["BestFitParameters"]  
fit1 = NonlinearModelFit[polar[[All, 2]], a n^b, {{a, 0.5}, b}, n]  
ListPlot[{polar[[All, 2]], const Sqrt[Range[Length@florets]]}]
ListPlot[{polar[[All, 2]], fit1 /@ Range[Length@florets]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

much better.

```
(*I think something is wrong with the angle model*)

fit = NonlinearModelFit[polar[[All, 1]], {Mod[ang n - offset, 2 Pi, -Pi], -Pi <= offset <= Pi}, {{ang, 1}, {offset, 1}}, n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
angles = Differences[polar[[All, 1]]]
angles = 2 Pi*UnitStep[angles] - angles
Histogram[angles, {0, 2 Pi, 0.2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Doesn't look constant to me :(

```
fitr = fit1 /@ Range[Length@florets];
fittheta = fit /@ Range[Length@florets];
fitpolar = Transpose[{fittheta, fitr}];

ListPolarPlot[{polar, fitpolar}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Still not great, looks like the angle between each floret is not a constant.

Moving the center position doesn't seem to dramatically improve the fit of `r(n)`

```
rdata[{x0_, y0_}] := 
 Module[{}, 
  fit = LinearModelFit[
    SortBy[(Transpose@
        Reverse@Transpose@
          CoordinateTransform[
           "Cartesian" -> "Polar", # - {x0, y0} & /@ florets])[[All, 
       2]], Last], Sqrt[n], n, IncludeConstantBasis -> False];
  {x0, y0, First@fit["BestFitParameters"], fit["AdjustedRSquared"]}
  ]
coords = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y}, {x, -0.01, 0.01, 0.001}, {y, -0.01, 0.01, 0.001}], 1];
output = rdata /@ coords;
output[[First@First@Position[output[[All, 4]], Max[output[[All, 4]]]]]]
Histogram[output[[All, 4]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think it's probably unrealistic to expect the structure of a particular actual flower to match an idealized mathematical model. In fact the linked question already shows clearly enough that some arms of the spiral are of different lengths and/or have different origins (offsets relative to the centre) than the others.

Comment: I wasn't confident enough in my code to blame the model, and rightly so since you found errors in it, but now I guess we know. Thank you very much.