# Fibonacci spiral in sunflower

Tags: image-processing

How to find and detect the  [Fibonacci spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_spiral) in sunflower image?

[image]

and how to get the following graph from initial image?

[image]

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20924) is related.

Comment: Claiming that patterns on sunflower seeds (or many other things in nature) would be specifically Fibonacci spirals is a bit of hype. Similar they may be, but those processes don't necessarily converge to this single pattern.

Comment: @kirma Yup, as I found out [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39772/731).

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun:

```
fun[r_, p_, t_] := r {Cos[2 Pi t/p], Sin[2 Pi t/p]}
fb[n_, t_, col_] := 
 Module[{tab, a = Fibonacci[n], b = Fibonacci[n - 1]},
  tab = Table[
    Line[{fun[1, a, j], fun[1, b, j]}], {j, 0, LCM[a, b], 
     LCM[a, b]/t}];
  Graphics[{col, Disk[{0, 0}, 1], White, tab}, Background -> Black, 
   ImageSize -> 400]]
```

Visualizing:

```
res = Column[{Row[{"{", Fibonacci[#], ",", Fibonacci[# - 1], "}"}], 
      fb[#, 1000, Red]}] & /@ Range[4, 10];
grid = Grid[Partition[res, 3]];
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
i0 = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cOud.jpg";
i1 = ImageCrop[i0, 380, {Left, Bottom}];
i2 = ColorConvert[ImageResize[i1, 200], "GrayScale"] // ImageAdjust;
i3 = ImageMultiply[
   ImageMultiply[i2, 
    ImagePad[
     ImageResize[Graphics[{White, Disk[]}, Background -> Black], 
      ImageDimensions@i2/1.2], First@ImageDimensions@i2]],
   ImagePad[ImageResize[Graphics[{Disk[]}], ImageDimensions@i2/2], 
    First@ImageDimensions@i2, Padding -> White]];
i4 = ColorConvert[i3, "Grayscale"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cents = # - ImageDimensions@i4/2 & /@ 
   ComponentMeasurements[Erosion[MorphologicalBinarize[i4, .6], 1], 
     "Centroid"][[All, 2]];

rot[ang_, pts_] := RotationTransform[ang] /@ pts

f = Nearest[cents];

ListPlot[{cents, rot[0, cents]}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
cross[{a_, b_}] := Sign@Last@Cross[Join[a, {0}], Join[#, {0}]] & /@ b
dist[{a_, b_}] := If[Norm@# > Norm@a, 1000, Norm[a - #]] & /@ b

lines[i_] := 
  Transpose[{Last /@ 
     First /@ (SortBy[#, #[[2]] &] & /@ (Select[#, #[[1]] == 
              i &] & /@ (Transpose[{cross@#, 
               dist@#, #[[2]]}] & /@ ({#, Rest@f[#, 7]} & /@ 
              cents)))), cents}];


GraphicsRow[ ColorCombine[{i4, 
     ColorNegate@ ImageResize[ Graphics[{Thick, Line /@ lines[#]}, 
        PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-100, 100}}, 
        AspectRatio -> 1], {200, 201}]}] & /@ {1, -1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]